# Problems retrieving inserted entries in the same request - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am having a problem which I am stuck on for quite a while now.

I am building a travel finance tracker with Laravel. The problem is when I insert several rows into the database within one request and then try to retrieve them to recalculate the total amount of all spendings, it only returns the first entry of the inserted rows. The entries are all there when I check the database and if I try to retrieve them in a seperate request, it returns all of them.

Does anybody know, what the reason for this behaviour could be?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Sebastian

Comment: Please share the code where you're trying to retrieve the data. You can use http://laravel.io/bin

Comment: Show the code of how you insert the data and how you retrieve it.